# jquery "or" statement

Tags: jquery

How do i use an "or" statement in jquery, i have two separate statements that i think i can combine to be just one:

```
$('li.members').hover(function() {
    $('.members-show').show();
    $('.brokers-show').hide();
    $('.providers-show').hide();
    $('.employers-show').hide();
    $('.seniors-show').hide();
    return false;
  });

$('li.members-active').hover(function() {
    $('.members-show').show();
    $('.brokers-show').hide();
    $('.providers-show').hide();
    $('.employers-show').hide();
    $('.seniors-show').hide();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: if, for some reason, combining selectors in the way Ryan suggested wouldn't do it for you (theoretically; if, say, you were adding the same functionality to the hover of one item and to live click of another item - in your example Ryan's answer is indeed the way to go), you would still be able to refactor this, by creating a separate function: `function doStuff() { ... } $('li.members').hover(doStuff); $('sthElse').live('click', doStuff);` Just thought I should add that =)

Comment: If you're not expecting to reverse the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions when the mouse leaves, then you might as well use `.mouseenter()` instead of `.hover()`. Right now, the handler is firing a second time with no visible effect when the mouse leaves `li.members`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('li.members, li.members-active').hover(function() {
    $('.members-show').show();
    $('.brokers-show').hide();
    $('.providers-show').hide();
    $('.employers-show').hide();
    $('.seniors-show').hide();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Also: `$('.brokers-show, .providers-show, .employers-show, .seniors-show').hide()`. (Probably the entire `*-show` suffix could be dropped for a separate CSS class `show`, which could be added and dropped with `addClass()` and `removeClass`…)

Answer (score 10):

```
$('li.members, li.members-active').hover(function() {
    $('.members-show').show();
    $('.members-show, .providers-show, .employers-show, .seniors-show').hide();    
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Almost - the $().hide() selector needs commas. But +1 for combining those calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('li.members,li.members-active').hover(function() {
    $('.members-show').show();
    $('.brokers-show').hide();
    $('.providers-show').hide();
    $('.employers-show').hide();
    $('.seniors-show').hide();
    return false;
  });
```